# azure function webhook key

Tags: azure, key, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am not able to make the azure generic webhook function work with 
authlevel keys (function/host/anonymous etc.)
I created a generic webhook function. I understand it is by default protected with function key auth level - is this correct? In such case how to change the authlevel to Host or anonymous? 
Next I am calling it from a request-response logic app flow. So I get a request, call the function and then respond back with the result from the function. From the code view of logic app I cannot see any function call that is taking the code and client as parameters. So my question is why is the function call not failing. Is this happening in anonymous mode? Or is there any way the logic app is calling the function with the appropriate parameters (code and clientid) which is not shown even in the code view? Perhaps I am missing some very basic thing - appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

> In such case how to change the authlevel to Host or anonymous?

When creating a generic webhook function, you could set the mode for your trigger  and the **Mode** notes as follows:

> The mode of the trigger. "Standard" means that the request will be standard HTTP with no additional semantics. "Webhook" means that the request will be processed according to a specified webhook type.

The `authLevel` property in `function.json` file does not apply to the WebHook triggers. To trigger a WebHook function the HTTP request must include an API key (e.g. `https://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function>?code=<Host key or Function key>`). You could choose your generic webhook function, choose your HTTP trigger, then click the **Documentation** link for more detailed tutorials about HTTP and webhook bindings.

> Next I am calling it from a request-response logic app flow. So I get a request, call the function and then respond back with the result from the function.

Based on your scenario, I did the sample flow as follows:

[image]

You just need to choose your generic webhook function and logic app would handle the authorization for you. Moreover, the API keys are stored under `D:\home\data\Functions\secrets` folder, you could use [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) and find them in the `host.json` or `<function-name>.json` file. Also, here is a [tutorial](http://blog.octavie.nl/index.php/2017/04/20/get-the-default-azure-function-key-with-powershell) using PowerShell to access [KUDU REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) for retrieving Azure Function key. Additionally, you could add your comment [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/).

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed answers - very helpful details. I did get some confirmations on some areas of my questions but there are other areas where need some more clarity. I need to split my response into multipart as follows due to character restriction in comments. Perhaps this is not the right way to include large comments please pardon me and let me know if there is better way to put large comments.

Comment: To my original questions.  1) authlevel -> I had already seen the documentation in function integration tab it clearly mentions "authLevel : Doesn't apply to WebHook triggers". However the document at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) seems bit vague. It mentions slack and github don't support authlevel but doesn't mention the same for genericJson. Hence confusion.  However on your answer, changing mode to standard means it is no longer webhook type. So means we cannot set a webhook to anonymous access anyway- correct?

Comment: 2) The second question was why can't I see the keys being passed when the function app is being called from a logic app. Thanks for trying out the flow - actually the flow works for me too. Unfortunately from your response I cannot locate a clear answer to the question. Perhaps as you mention this is taken care by logic app and this is all internal to logic app - and that it is passing internally but there is no way to visualize the same in the call?  Can you please clarify this part.

Comment: 3) Finally you mention that keys are present in .json files in the secret folder. Though I had seen these files earlier but had not paid much attention. After you mentioned I took a careful look and found the keys to be different than the ones shown on the portal function manage page. Is this because the keys are encrypted? So I understand that the only way to see these key values are either via portal or via Kudu powershell as you mentioned - is this correct?

Comment: 1) Per my test, the webhook could not anonymous access.You could [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#test-a-function-within-functions](Test a function within functions) on azure or  [Test a function with tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#test-a-function-with-tools). 2) I did not found any official documentation for this processing, you could add your comment under [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/). 3) The key is encrypted,the `encrypted` property is true under the `host.json`.